# How to customize Asp.Net Identity UserId

Tags: asp.net-identity

I want to set the UserId to `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")` instead of the default one in the IdentityUser; `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("")`;

Any simple idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Id to what you want when creating a new user in the system. A better approach would be to set the Id on your ApplicationUser constructor:

```
public class ApplicationUser :  IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
        : base()
    {
        if(this.Id == null)
           this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    } 
....
```